# How to remove Resharper warning in Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Test Data Value: {0}", data))?

Tags: c#, resharper, visual-studio-debugging

I want to remove the warning in the following code that will be warned by Resharper as "Redundant 'string.Format' call".

```
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Test Data Value: {0}", data));
```

I think everything with Debug class will not be included in release Mode by compiler and Debug will be used only in Debug mode.
So why Resharper cares about string.Format if it will be removed anyway.
But this code will work even though in Release mode both will be warned.

```
string message = string.Format("Test Data Value: {0}", data);
Debug.WriteLine(message);
```

The code above will not be warned by Resharper but message variable will become a trash in release if is not optimized.
I ask this question because there are a lot of such code and if I use "Suppress inspection" then the code will be bigger and not clean.
**How to remove the warning?**

Comment: Is the warning still there if you change it to: `string message = "Test Data Value: " + data;`

Comment: Why not just use the overload that does the same thing instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Szymon, Yes there is no warning, I will use that if the string is simple, but many code use more complex variables that Format should be used.

Comment: @Arran, that exactly what I want! +1 For you. I didn't know that WriteLine is like implementation of string.Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can, of course, suppress the warning - ReSharper is very flexible in terms of telling it to "shut up".

However, I'd say, ReSharper is a little helpful here. The `string.Format` is very redundant for the simple reason is that `Debug.WriteLine` has an overload which mimics the same thing:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153(v=vs.110).aspx

I'd suggest a *better* solution would be to replace your uses of `Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(....));` with `Debug.WriteLine("Test Data Value: {0}", data)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma warning disable
//Your code with warnings
#pragma warning restore
```

Comment: Like I said that these code are a lot in our code, so if use pragma, the code will be dirty and bigger.